# Comments not displaying from rendered form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby and I am trying to display comments on my show page but when I create a comment it does not display. I have rendered a partial on my show page in order to display the comments but they do not appear.

The strange thing is that the create action works but it takes me to this page: `http://localhost:3000/hairstyles/2/comments` which has nothing on it (in my app this page is under views>comments>create.html.erb) instead i'd like it to go to the view page for the hairstyle and display the comment..........

If anyone can help and see if there are any errors in my code I'd be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comments Controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:hairstyle_id])
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:hairstyle_id])
    @comment.save   

  end

  def destroy
  end
end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
  end
```

Hairstyle view page where I want to display the comments:

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <%= cl_image_tag @hairstyle.photo, width: 300, height: 200, crop: :fill %>
    <h1><%= @hairstyle.name %></h1>
    <p><%= @hairstyle.description%></p>
    <p><%= @hairstyle.category%></p>
    <p><%= @hairstyle.video_url %></p>
  </div>
</div>
 <div>
    <%= link_to 'Back', hairstyles_path %>
 </div>

<h6>Comments for: <%= @hairstyle.name %> <small><%= %></small></h6>
<h2>
  <%= pluralize @hairstyle.comments.size, "comment" %>
</h2>

<div id="comments">
  <% if @hairstyle.comments.blank? %>
    Be the first to leave a comment for <%= @hairstyle.name %>
  <% else %>
    <% @hairstyle.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <%= render 'comments/show', comment: comment %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<%= render 'comments/form', comment: @comment %>
```

Comments form i am rendering which does work and is displayed:
views>comments>_form.html.erb

```
<div class="flex-box">
  <%= simple_form_for([ @hairstyle, comment ]) do |form| %>
    <%= form.input :content, as: :text %>
    <%= form.button :submit %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comments content that I am rendering that does not display once I have added a comment to my hairstyle on the show page:

views>comments>_show.html.erb

```
<p><%= comment.content %></p>
```

Comment: something to keep in mind: Rails has a special convenience method for rendering collections (`@hairstyle.comments` in your example): https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections — better performance and more concise.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of rails controllers is it will redirect to the index page after the create method. that's why you are redirected to that path.

you can simply use `redirec_to` in your `create`  method in your comment controller like below

```
def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:hairstyle_id])
    @comment.save   
    redirect_to hairstyle_path(@comment.hairstyle)
end
```

Comment: Hi there, OK I see so once my comment is created if I do not tell it to redirect to the a specific page it will not. OK understood. I have now added the code you provided above in my create method and I get the following error: ``No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"hairstyles", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]`` here are my routes: ``resources :hairstyles do <br/>
  resources :comments, only: [:new, :create ]<br/>
  resources :saved_hairstyles, only: [:new, :create]<br/>
end`` to me they look fine... Any ideas?

Comment: I mean that explicitly redirect to your hairstyle show path I don't know how you configure that path, so use that path instead of mine :)

Comment: your error saying that hairstyle is nil, please provide particular hairstly id

Comment: Hello Vishal, arr ok but hairstyle_path is my SHOW page, it is the page I want to redirect to...........  I don't know what you mean by provide particular hairstyle id, as hairstyle id is nil  :S I think I am not understanding but I will play around and see what I come up with thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You never link your comment to your hairstyle, your `hairstyle_id` from your comment is `nil` this is why `@hairstyle.comments` returns an empty array

```
def create
  @hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:hairstyle_id])
  @comment = @hairstyle.comments.build(comment_params)
  # equivalent to:
  # comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  # comment.hairstyle = @hairstyle

  if comment.save
    redirect_to hairstyle_path(@hairstyle)
  else 
    # handle errors
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Vincent thank you for your response, when you say I didn't link my comment to my hairstyle is this what you are doing on line 2 of the create method above? ``@hairstyle.comments.build(comment_params)`` I've never seen the method .build before

Comment: Yes it is! i have edited my answer to feature a more understandable approach

Comment: Oh great makes sense now. So if I do this it should work? Let me see what happens. Thank you!

Comment: Hello there ok so now I am back to where I started. It works but when I click create comment it redirects to ```http://localhost:3000/hairstyles/2/comments``` which is not what I want, I want it to redirect to the hairstyle show page and display the comments below the hairstyle. :S so weird, in my terminal it says rollback at line 32 of my comments controller which is the line ``if comment.save`` I will play around with the redirect path and see...

Comment: I think this is because your comment is probably not valid (case to handle in the else branch above) .

Comment: oh ok I see, I will write some logic in the 'else' statement above then, great thanks!